# Why are my 'medium' images the wrong size

Tags: images, thumbnails

In my media settings I have:

```
Thumbnail size  131 x 87
Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions: yes
Medium size     260 x 1000
Large size          560 x 800
```

But the_post_thumbnail('medium') outputs an image of size 180 x 194px (originally 580 x 630). What have I done wrong?

If I look at get_intermediate_image_sizes() I see:

```
Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => large
    [3] => kc-large
    [4] => slider
    [5] => post-thumbnail
)
```

kc-large and slider are both set in my theme, I think post-thumbnail is a WordPress thing. If I use the Force Regenerate Thumbnails plugin I see that it generates my medium sized images correctly.

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Toby

Comment: images are resized when they're uploaded, if you uploaded images before you changed the size, those old images will not be automatically resized.

Comment: As Milo says, if this is the case for you [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails) worked/works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your responses - I'm actually using an image resizing plugin, as mentioned. I think, however, it was user error this time - when I ran the plugin on all images I got the expected result. I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but it must have been something daft.